# How can I avoid the data set retaining old edited but inaccessible data

Tags: xml, runtime, editing, tclientdataset

I have a Clientdataset whose Fielddefs are loaded and values added at run time.  There is no indexing and no provider and the data set is saved straight to a XML file.
If I alter the values (just word types) then new records are created but the old row data are retained and saved in the xml file but are NOt associated with records.  Furthermore, the redundant, inactive rows mulltiply with successive reads and saves.
This is the code

```
 `CFCDS.First;
 While not CFCDS.eof do 
 begin
      GetCFGComps();
      CFCDS.next;
 end;`

Procedure GetCFGComps();
    var  j: integer;
    Begin 
        for j := 0 to 14 do 
        begin                           {READ values to record}
              case j of
                  0: FldPos.L   := CFCDS.Fields[j].Value;
                  1: FldPos.T   := CFCDS.Fields[j].Value;
                  ...........
              end; 
        end; 
        with FldPos do begin
            L  := 550;
            T  := 69;
            W  := 333;
        end; 
        for J := 0 to 14 do 
        begin
            case j of
               0: CFCDS.Fields[j].Value:=FldPos.L;
               1: CFCDS.Fields[j].Value:=FldPos.T;
                      ....................
            end;
        end;
        CFCDS.SaveToFile(CFGFileName, dfXML);
        j:= CFCDS.RecordCount;           //always 50 - the correct number
        CFCDS.First;                     
        FldPos.L       := CFCDS.Fields[1].Value;         //returns new values
        CFCDS.SaveToFile(DIRY+'CFTEXT.cft',dfBinary);    //also has old supernumery rows  
   end; `
```

[image: This is section of the xml file showing the last of the previous data set (Rowstate = "5" and the start of the new active data set below the red line Rowstate = "12"]
I can think of clumsy ways around this like creating a temporary data set, deleting the working data set and then saving using the record data for values which are not changed.
I appreciate that CDS can create new records if it finds some disagreeable but this is a very simple change in values.
If I remove the code: 
        with FldPos do begin
                L  := 550;
                T  := 69;
                W  := 333;
            end; 
the XML file is clean with just the record data (all rows Rowstate"4").

Does anyone have a suggestion how the data set can be programmatically edited 
 so old inaccessible data is not retained and it contains only row data of records? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found solution:  `CFCDS.LogChanges:= false;`